# Tick labels above axis

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

Is there any way to place tick marks on the x-axis **above** the axis? Note that I am talking about marks on the axis, not on a frame (because my graph has no frame). To be more specific, here's the reason I need that: I have a graph of a lower semi-circle with some shading generated by the following code:

```
ClearAll[x, y, a];
gthick = Thickness[0.005];
g1 = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 1 , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -0.6, 0}, Frame -> False];
g2 = Plot[-Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, gthick}];
g3 = ListLinePlot[{{-0.8, -0.6}, {0.8, -0.6}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, gthick}];
g4 = Graphics[{Dashing[Small], Line[{{-0.8, -0.6}, {-0.8, 0}}],
   Line[{{0.8, -0.6}, {0.8, 0}}]}];
Show[{g1, g2, g3, g4}, PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 0.2}},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
   Ticks -> {{{-1.05, -1, 0}, {-0.65, -Sqrt[1 - a^2], 0}, {0.65, Sqrt[1 - a^2], 0},
   {1.05, 1, 0}}, None}, TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15]]
```

And the output (anybody can check that) is:

[image]

Anybody can see that on a picture like this, so that it looks nice, tick labels should be above the x-axis. But how?

P.S. (edited) I know that I can add text on the graph at desired positions. But can it be achieved with tick labels being tick labels, thru some options?

Comment: Hello, please see the linked question for an answer. That question talks about flipping it for the y-axis, but it should be easily extendable. In particular, I think Istvan's answer already addresses this.

Comment: Even without that, here's a simple modification to yours that achieves the same look: `Show[{g1, g2, g3, g4}, PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 0}},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
    FrameTicks -> {{{-1.05, -1, 0}, {-0.65, -Sqrt[1 - a^2], 
     0}, {0.65, Sqrt[1 - a^2], 0},
       {1.05, 1, 0}}, None}, TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15], 
 Frame -> {False, False, True, False}, PlotRangePadding -> 0]`

Comment: @rm-rf: Yes, that one (from the linked question) kinda does answer my question... except for what he suggested there is a smart way of placing text on the graph at the positions of the desired tick labels. I was wondering if there are some options for _Mathematica_'s own tick labels for that, but it looks like probably not...

Comment: Please see my second comment above... it's simple if you use frames and frame ticks.

Comment: @rm-rf: Yeah, I saw it and I tried it. But it only works if the x-axis is the top boundary of the picture. If I extend the vertical axis up with `PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 0.5}}`, as it was in my original code (and I need that), this doesn't work anymore. So I guess I'm gonna have to go to that linked question and learn his approach. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... ok. Unfortunately, ticks are a sore point in _Mathematica_ and I'm afraid that the cumbersome approach in the linked post is the best general solution available right now. If you have trouble implementing the answer there for your example above, please ping me and I'll try to help. :)