# Flipping y-tick labes or x-tick labels simply

Tags: plotting

As it is common to most of us, when we plot a figure, x label ticks are located above x-axis and y label ticks are located at the right of y-axis. Is there any simple way to alter this in `Mathematica`? I am more interested in y-axis labels (numbers) because they overlap with the graph content. I would be happy to see them at the right side of the y-axis. Have any idea? Thanks in advance.[image]

Below is an example. If I move the axis origin to $(0,0)$, then the numbers overlap with the figure. I need to flip both the ticks and the numbers.

Comment: something like `Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {{{Pi, 180 \[Degree], {0, .03}}, {2 Pi, 360 \[Degree], {0, .03}}, {3 Pi, 540 \[Degree], {0, .03}}}, {#, #, {0., .02}} & /@  Range[-1, 1, .2]}]`?

Comment: @kguler in princip yes but I also need the numbers to be flipped as the ticks. Namely, if the y-axis ticks are looking to the left then the numbers should be at right.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [(2601)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2601/121),
[(6395)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6395/121), 
[(42209)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42209/121).  (Sadly there is no satisfying answer that I am aware of.)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I checked the asked questions especially this one : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/is-it-possible-to-position-ticklabels-on-the-negative-y-axis-on-its-right-side but I was not able to manipulate the answers to get an answer and I believe that it can be more useful it there could be some more practical answer, although I doubt there can be, because it seems a non trival thing.

Comment: Although there is one trick you might use, which I shall attempt in a minute, I fear that you may need to draw your own ticks entirely.  For an example of what is involved see this: [(23910)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23910/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I see. The people are crazy. It is really unbelievable what people can do with this Mathematica and how some simple looking things might need real efforts)

Comment: When the system outright lacks the functionality you seek reimplementation can be very painful. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post-processing the `FullGraphics` of `Plot` output to change the positions of ticks and tick labels of the vertical axis:

```
Graphics[Replace[First[FullGraphics[plt1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}]]],
  {Text[a_, b_, {1., 0.}] :> Text[Pane[a, 30, Alignment -> Left], b, -{2, 0}],
   Line[{{0., b_ /; b != 0}, {c_, b_}}] :> Line[{{0., b}, {-3 c, b}}]}, {0, Infinity}],
   ImageSize -> 500, plt1[[2]][[1]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have exactly the same style (the number of ticks, the outlook and the number of numbers (-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1 in this example)) of the ticks of the original figure.

Comment: Sadly this no longer works in version 10 as `FullGraphics` is broken.  This was the first thing I tried.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard & seyhmus,  this has some glitches in V9 too;  `FullGraphics[plt1]` "should" display the same as `plt1` but it doesn't; it changes the ticks. I am afraid creating ticks and labels separately (that is, not relying on post-processing) seems to be the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the elegant method of kguler does not work in Mma 10, one can draw everything "by hand":

```
     lst1 = Join[Table[Line[{{-0.05, 0.1 i}, {0, 0.1 i}}], {i, -10, 10, 1}], 
   Table[Line[{{-0.08, 0.5 i}, {0, 0.5 i}}], {i, -2, 2, 1}]];
lst2 = Table[Text[Style[0.5 i, 12, Italic], {-0.3, 0.5 i}], {i, -2, 2, 1}];
lst3 = Table[Line[{{\[Pi]*i/2, -0.05}, {\[Pi]*i/2, 0}}], {i, 1, 4, 1}];
lst4 = Table[Text[Style[\[Pi]*i/2, 12, Italic], {\[Pi]*i/2, -0.3}], {i, 1, 4,1}];

Show[{
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Ticks -> None, 
   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 2 \[Pi]+0.5}, Automatic}],
  Graphics[{lst1, lst3}],
  Graphics[{lst2, lst4}]
  }]
```

yielding this:
[image]

Have fun!